# Override Magento Success Message in Contact Us Form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In Magento 1.7 the message **“Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.”** that we get when the default contact us is successfully submitted is used by

```
app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php
```

The translate (.csv) file used by the module is:

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Contacts.csv
```

I'm trying to override it in:
    app/design/frontend/MyTheme/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv

But thus far have been unsuccessful... Do I really need to override the controller action using a custom module just to translate this message?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system hasn't been core altered, or there's no code pool override, or existing rewrite that changes the message, then this is the line of code that adds that message

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
->addSuccess(
    Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.')
);
```

The string

```
'Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'
```

is passed through the `__` translate/localize function, which means that text is alterable through both Magento's CSV and inline translation feature.

This [Magento Stack Exchange question about the translation feature](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/6725) may help you debug your current system and explain why the translation isn't work the way you think it should. (since your question didn't mention it, my guess is cache)